# Is is ok to download apk from my app and let the user install it from my app

Tags: android, google-play

Hi I've two apps(one is main app and other is plugin) which works together. Now I published these two apps on play store. Now let say user install my main app. Can I download the other apk(plugin app) from my server in main app and when user click on a button on my main app I'll open the installation screen of plugin apk from where user can click on install button to install it? I want to know is it fine to download apk? Or will Google suspend my app?

Comment: Your users will get an error.

Comment: What error? If he checked the Unknown Sources in setting? will user still get the error?

Comment: We can easily install apps from sd card by clicking on it. If Unknown sources is checked in settings

Comment: @Sunny: Yes, but users should not enable that.

Comment: @SLaks Yes you are right. User should not enable that. But I want to do so because user may not be interested in installing another app from play store. On the other side by downloading apk from my app it would be very easy for user to install the downloaded apk.

Comment: No; users will vastly prefer to click an extra button in the Play Store as opposed to enabling a security hole (complete with scary warnings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask users to download the second app.

You can check if the app is installed in the device and otherwise show a dialog to ask to open the store. If user agrees, then redirect to the app play store.

If you need code to do this let me know.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I decided that I'll open play store and will not download the apk myself.